# What can cause Android UI to stop updating?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

This is a problem that kind of baffles me. I'm an experienced developer, but I am pretty new on Android and Xamarin, so I thought I'd mine the ole SO for expert input.

My app has started behaving strangely - **sometimes the UI just.. stops drawing things**, when exchanging a Fragment. -It's like it just gives up in the middle of drawing, so you can see that for example a label which is supposed to have the text "Search" just has the text "Sea".

Everything else in the fragment is blank, though it seems that the fragment has been created OK, and it has a filled out-layouted view and everything, when I'm debugging.

Interestingly enough; **if I switch away from the app, in Android, and then back again - everything is dandy and works fine again!**

There's too much code to post - what I'm looking for is clues - what kind of situation is this behaviour a symptom of? What should I start looking for?

Comment: It looks like something is blocking ui thread , could you post the code so that we could reproduce the issue first ?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help out, but there is too much code to post in any reasonable way. I found the problem and will document it in this post

Answer (score 0):

The problem was twofold:

1. We tried to change the text in a UI label, from a timer handler, which was not OK, since the timer handler was in the wrong thread for that
2. This caused an exception which seemingly crashed the UI thread (I guess!), but due to settings in Visual Studio, this exception was not shown; hence the "unexplainable UI crash"

Comment: Try to invoke the text change on ui thread , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread .